# Button click not fired if the div is moving down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, the use case there is a div, one button and one textbox.

On the blur event of the textbox the div expands

and when button is clicked an alert is shown.

So both of these things work. but if my cursor is on the textbox  and I try to click on the button. Then click is not raised. I understand that, since button has moved click is not getting raised. So, what are my options

**Plunker of the code**

http://plnkr.co/edit/TYXLeE?p=preview

Comment: Side note: use `console.log()` rather than alert for testing

Comment: @Mohit if any of the answers to this question helped you, please consider accepting or up-voting said answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kVATTI?p=preview)

Just listen for mousedown instead, truely that is what you are looking for anyway.

```
  $('#clickAbleButton').on('mousedown',function() {
```

A click is 3 events not one, and they all must occur on the same element,

1. MouseDown
2. MouseUp
3. Click

The element moves out of the way before mouseup, so just listen for mousedown instead.

---

Really though, why are you moving the button mid click? I suspect this problem is really a design problem and should be addressed as such not hacked around with javascript.

Comment: Eventhough i had provided the same thing in my answer, i never believe mouseDown is a replacement for click. Because as you said while holding down the mouse i should be able to revert my decision to click. I dont believe the one in the timeout is good either.. but just some of the options... :)

Comment: I agree. But this user has a design problem in reality, asking a user to click on a moving button, wtf is that? I just feel this is clearner and less magic.

Comment: True... It is asking for bad usability on a end user point of view as well... especially if you are presenting to a customer its asking for trouble...

Comment: Yeah, moving an element on blur, bad bad bad.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. The usecase is that there is a form with input controls, there is a button that is suppose to clear all the input controls and validation messages. 

The client side validations are firing on blur of the input controls and these messages have to go away as well. 

Even with the mousedown that usecase would not work. Since, mouse down will fire clear the fields then onblur will get fired showing the validation messages.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is not an event issue, but that your validation script displays messages on pristine fields. You should be tracking a pristine state and a dirty state, so the form is aware of the difference between a field left blank by error, and one cleared by the user.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution on index.html:**

```
<body>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
 <input type="button" id="clickAbleButton" value="Click Me" />
<input type="text" id="myInputText" value="Empty Text Box" />
<div style="height:40px;" id="everExpandingDiv">
  This is my container div
</div>
```

**OR, best solution on script.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#myInputText').on('mousedown',function()     
    {$('#everExpandingDiv').height($('#everExpandingDiv').height()+20);});
    $('#clickAbleButton').click(function() {
       alert('button click was raised');
    });
});
```

Comment: Put the button at top and div at bottom. (index.html solution)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the .bind and .unbind jquery functions for the necessary click events